# Flutter Arcore not displaying 2d image on plane?

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality, arcore

I am trying to make an application which maps an image to a detected plane through the device camera, but it won't display the image.

I am using a Motorola g53 5g which supports depth api.

Please note that an image ('earth.jpg') should be in the projects lib/images/ directory as it is referenced in the code.

I am fairly inexperienced with Flutter/Dart, so please explain your answer if relevant.

This is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:arcore_flutter_plugin/arcore_flutter_plugin.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart' as vector;


class ImageObjectScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageObjectScreenState createState() => _ImageObjectScreenState();
}

class _ImageObjectScreenState extends State<ImageObjectScreen> {
  ArCoreController? arCoreController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Image object'),
        ),
        body: ArCoreView(
          onArCoreViewCreated: _onArCoreViewCreated,
          enableTapRecognizer: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onArCoreViewCreated(ArCoreController controller) {
    arCoreController = controller;
    arCoreController?.onPlaneTap = _handleOnPlaneTap;
  }

  Future _addImage(ArCoreHitTestResult hit) async {
    final bytes =
    (await rootBundle.load('images/earth.jpg')).buffer.asUint8List();

    final earth = ArCoreNode(
      image: ArCoreImage(bytes: bytes, width: 500, height: 500),
      position: hit.pose.translation + vector.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      rotation: hit.pose.rotation + vector.Vector4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    );

    arCoreController?.addArCoreNodeWithAnchor(earth);
  }

  void _handleOnPlaneTap(List<ArCoreHitTestResult> hits) {
    final hit = hits.first;
    _addImage(hit);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    arCoreController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

The application opens the camera in the app, and it seems to detect surfaces (it puts white dots on surfaces), but nothing happens. WHat is supposed to happen is that an image should be mapped to the surface and scaleable/rotatable.

The AndroidManifest.xml has the required permissions that are in alignment with documentation. The build.gradle of the project and the app, likewise, reference the appropriate SDK's, dependencies etc., and I have also tried to modify some of them. The image asset is referenced in assets in the pubspec.yaml with

```
  assets:
    - lib/images/
```

I have read all there is online to try and solve it, but i need help.